Renamed flags on Apple Mail in Mac do not show up in Apple Mail in iOS
I have couple of emails that I flagged with Orange flag on Apple Mail in Mac. I renamed the Orange flag to something more meaningful. I am now able to search the flag with the new name on Apple Mail in Mac.
But when I search for the renamed flag name on Apple Mail in iOS it does not work. But I can search by typing 'Orange' in the search bar.
Why does the renamed flag does not show up in Apple Mail in iOS?
